# Where can I find shapefiles or geospatial data for postal codes/ Código de Endereçamento Postal for Brazil

Tags: shapefile, data, geojson, postal-code, brazil

I am looking for shape files for Brazilian postal codes. I have looked at [IBGE](http://www.ibge.gov.br/home/) site and other sources but could not find anything. Free shape files will be better since we plan to use them for commercial purposes.

Comment: For open data often the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange is the first place to research/ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Wikipedia page on the topic (Código de Endereçamento Postal) :

> The complete postal code database, known as DNE, contains more than
>   900,000 codes (including streets, neighborhoods, cities and Federated
>   state names). Initially it was freely available at the Brazilian post
>   office website, but after receiving various enhancements it is now a
>   paid service.

You can likely purchase access from the [official website](http://www.correios.com.br), or utilize the
[viewer](http://www.buscacep.correios.com.br/servicos/dnec/menuAction.do?Metodo=menuEndereco).